# Douglas Crockford says we should use that=this. So why do some JS developers disagree?

Tags: javascript

If you watch enough Douglas Crockford videos on Youtube, you'll see that to get an outer `this` he does stuff like

```
var that = this; 
$('p').each(function(){
    that._textPieces.push($(this).text());
});
```

which is why I do the same. Yet I know that some JS developers consider that shoddy and instead use `bind` and all the other ways that use more language features and yet make the code more unreadable because a reader has to go to more work to figure out what `this` means in the exact context in which it is used.

Comment: Crockford's a old crack. Get off his lawn!

Comment: More seriously: it's not very common that you'll have deeply-nested functions which use different values of `this` than the parent functions. Most of the time, `this` is consistent (or unused), so it's clearer to consistently refer to it as `this` instead of using a different name like `that`. (There are some cases where this isn't true, but I think they're a small minority in most code bases.) Crockford might be suggesting this because he's following practices established before `.bind()` existed.

Comment: You really should ask Crockford himself, not us, why he uses a syntax that others consider shoddy.

Comment: Your title question doesn't make sense. It sounds like you're suggesting that all JS developers would need to agree with Crockford?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: as several commenters have noted, it's generally preferred to use `.bind()` in ES5 and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in ES6.

There once was a dark age before `.bind()`, as evidenced by [the compatibility table at the bottom of this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind); Crockford is of that age.  As you can see from the `.bind()` polyfill (also on the MDN page), rolling your own *completely standards-correct* `.bind()` is non-trivial compared to a simple `var that = this;` - so it's not unreasonable to do the latter.

Of course, I'm not Crockford, so I have no idea what his thought process was way back when :)

With that in mind, this trick does come in handy on occasion.  For example, [d3](https://d3js.org/) has a `selection.each()` function, which is called for each element in the selection with that element bound to `this`.  `var that = this;` in the outer scope here allows me to access both the element and the outer scope `this`:

```
var that = this;
d3.selectAll('circle.foo')
  .each(function(d, i) {
    var circle = d3.select(this);
    var position = that.computePosition(circle);
    circle
      .attr('cx', position.x)
      .attr('cy', position.y);
  });
```

(This particular example is cribbed from some code where I didn't want to call `computePosition()` twice, as there were enough `circle.foo` DOM nodes that profiling had shown `computePosition()` to be a bottleneck.  You can imagine similar scenarios in jQuery and other such DOM manipulation libraries.)

Personally, I usually call `that` something a bit more visually distinct from `this` (e.g. `context`, `outerContext`, `outerThis`, etc.) to minimize confusion.

Comment: *Nowadays*, it's generally preferred to use arrow functions :-P

Comment: Good point.  Edited to mention ES5 vs. ES6.